# False longitudinale when calculating a new gps point with bearing, distance and startpoint in china

Tags: java

I am using a function created on the basis of this website and it works good. but i am facing a problem as mention in the heading, that the calculation does not work in china.

https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Calculate the distance and bearing between two gps points:
GPS point 1: 40.0166447,116.3063929
GPS point 2: 40.016705900000005,116.30665250000001
Distance in Meter:   14.511659385475214

I then use the below funciton to calculate the middlepoint but in China, I get a false longitude:

False output of the new Point: 40.01693515930434,63.69358559958683

Please give me a tip or a solution. What have I forgotten?

```
public static double[] middlPoint(double bearing, double distance, 
 double lat, double lon) {
        double[] ret = new double[2];
        double R = 6371;
        lat = Math.toRadians(lat);
        lon = Math.toRadians(lon);
        ret[0] = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat) * Math.cos(distance / R) + 
Math.cos(lat) * Math.sin(distance / R) * Math.cos(bearing));
        ret[1] = lon + Math.atan2(Math.sin(bearing) * Math.sin(distance / R) 
* Math.cos(lat),Math.cos(distance / R) - Math.sin(lat) * Math.sin(ret[0]));
        ret[0] = Math.toDegrees(ret[0]);
        ret[1] = Math.toDegrees((ret[1] + 540) % 360 - 180);        
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note the information about mcve. Also please format your code .

Comment: thanks c0der, i done the tour. thanks Dave2e to help.  Expected output should be the middle point from GPS1 and GPS2. Thats mean something with 116.xxxxxx and not 63.69358559958683. As i mentioned, in europe the algo works very good.